# Compress files while reading data from STDIN

Tags: linux, stdin, compression

Is it possible to compress (create a compressed archive) data while reading from stdin on Linux?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Unix & Linux

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Yes, use gzip for this. The best way is to read data as input and redirect the compressed to output file i.e.

```
cat test.csv | gzip > test.csv.gz
```

`cat test.csv` will send the data as stdout and using pipe-sign gzip will read that data as stdin. Make sure to redirect the gzip output to some file as compressed data will not be written to the terminal.

Comment: Note that the test.csv.gz files remains of 0 size until the data flux is closed.

Comment: ... and how does one do that?  Is it really a separate question?

Comment: This also works with `xz`: `mysqldump mydb | xz > dbdump.sql.xz`

Comment: Could use `-9`, default compression level is `-6`.

Comment: @MUY Belgium: not exactly, it starts writing only after 16KB of compressed blocks. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643078/tool-library-to-compress-decompress-on-the-fly/643084#643084)

Answer (score 114):

Yes, `gzip` will let you do this. If you simply run `gzip > foo.gz`, it will compress STDIN to the file foo.gz. You can also pipe data into it, like `some_command | gzip > foo.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

`gzip > stdin.gz` perhaps?  Otherwise, you need to flesh out your question.